# Diagnosing an unresponsive/suspending computer

Tags: ubuntu, diagnostic, unresponsive

My work computer has recently started freezing up. I'll leave it running and at some point I cannot SSH to it any more and when I check on it in person, it looks much like it went to sleep (the screens are turned off but don't give any "no signal" messages, the power button on the PC is still turned on, and the fans are still working). However, I cannot wake it up, regardless of what I do (I've tried moving the mouse, pressing keys, pressing ctrl+alt+del, and even the power button). So I have to force reboot it (by holding the power button).

I tried some solutions I found online to turn off sleep/suspend, such as turning off "Automatic Suspend" in Power settings, turning off "Suspend when laptop lid is closed" in gnome Tweaks, and adding `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` to `/etc/default/grub`. None of these prevented the issue.

I've also considered a hardware issue, so I ran memtest86 and got no errors. I also checked my SSD and HDD for errors and even tried replacing my GPU.

I'm kind of at a loss on how to continue diagnosing this problem. Are there perhaps some specific log files I could look at to get an idea of what's going on and whether it's a software or hardware issue? Some way to check for motherboard and CPU errors? Maybe even PSU errors?

Computer specs:

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 1700
- MB: MSI X370 SLI PLUS
- RAM: G.Skill Ripjaws V 16GB DDR4-3200
- GPU: NVIDIA Titan V

Comment: So the computer is booting up and running then freezes with black screen?

Comment: Set Power Management to leave the computer ON and disable Sleep and Hibernation. Allow the monitor to sleep.

Comment: @ChrisRogers Something like that, yes. However, it has never frozen on me while I was actively using it (so far).

Comment: @John I don't understand this comment. I don't have a tool called Power Management. In the Power section of Settings I've already tried disabling Automatic Suspend.

Comment: You did what I was suggesting. I just use Power Management in a generic sense.